# generate two .exe files from one app.config

Tags: c#, exe

I have project in C# in Visual Studio 2013.
I would like to generate two .exe files from one project (not create two separate projects that use the same solution folder). Exe files differ only in access to the databases (main and backup). First exe file should access only to the main database and second one only to the backup database. Is it possible to change somehow app.config to generate 2 exe files with different settings from one project?

Comment: I can't answer your question directly, but I'd suggest that it might be simplest to perform the build twice (from some script or other), passing in a build parameter that is referenced within the app.config through a #if directive.

Comment: I would love to make it this way, but I can't.

Comment: I think you may need to use pre build / post build events to change the DB access after building the first exe and then use the modified app.config to build the second exe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/specifying-custom-build-events-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In app use `connectionString` form app.config. VS does not directly support the transformation of app.config like web.config in web projects but there are plug-ins. For example: [SlowCheetah](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.%20SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms). 
And you can bulid different configs with different values in app.config.